# Given two metrics $g,$ and $h$, related by $h = e^{\frac{2f}{n}}g$, what is the relation between $\star_g$ and $\star_g$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Given two metrics $g,$ $h$, and a smooth function $f$ on a riemannian manifold $M^n$, supposing that $g$ and $h$ are related by $h = e^{\frac{2f}{n}}g$, what is the relation between $\star_g$ and $\star_h$? Where $\star$ is the Hodge star operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be found [here](https://anhngq.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/conformal-changes-of-riemannian-metrics/), it refers to the book on [Einstein manifolds](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540741206). Under the conformal change $\tilde g = e^{2f} g$, it is of the form (when acts on $p$-forms)

$$*_{\tilde g} = e^{(n-2p)f}  * _g.$$

For your interest, the codifferential $\delta$ is related by

$$\tilde \delta = e^{-2f} \left( \delta - (n-2p) \iota_{\nabla f}\right).$$

So if $2p = n$, both the Hodge star and the codifferential do not depends on $\nabla f$, which is quite amazing. In $n=2$ (the case of Riemann surfaces), the Hodge star operator on one form can be described solely by the complex/conformal structure of $M$.

Comment: thanks a lot, it helped too much.